# 404 not found error while deleting a table record with ajax and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to delete a table row with rails ajax. But i am getting the below error in my console.

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/spares 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is my code blocks.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', spare, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the #{spare.name}?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs",remote: true %></td>
```

destroy.js.erb file

```
//$('tr #<%= @spare.id %>').slideUp();
var element = document.getElementById(<%= @spare.id %>);
alert(element);
alert(hello); 
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

**The alert in the above code is also not showing up. **

Below is my table :

```
<% @spares.each_with_index do |spare, index| %>
      <tr id="li_<%= spare.id %>">
        <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= spare.name %></td>

        <!-- authorization check -->
        <% if can? :show, Spare %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', spare, class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs" %> 
        <% end %>

        <!-- authorization check -->
        <% if can? :edit, Spare %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_spare_path(spare), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %> 
         <% end %>

         <!-- authorization check -->
         <% if can? :destroy, Spare %>
           <%= link_to 'Destroy', spare, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the #{spare.name}?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs",remote: true %></td>
```

I checked the format being rendered in the rails panel and it shows js . But rendering doesnt show destroy.js.erb .

Below is the error in the server log

```
 "/spares" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-26 09:02:29 +0530
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/spares"):
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: `<%= @spare.id %>` would probably return an integer instead of a string. try `<%= @spare.id.to_s %>`.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt help . The destroy.js.erb file itself is not rendered as the alert also is not showing.

Comment: I have included my server log error

Comment: show us your routes for `spares` and your `SparesController#delete`

Comment: i have given resources:spares and   respond_to :html, :js in my controller. The delete works fine without remote:true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do this.

index.html.erb

```
    <% @spares.each_with_index do |spare, index| %>
      <tr id="li_<%= spare.id %>">
        <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= spare.name %></td>

      <!-- authorization check -->
      <% if can? :show, Spare %>
       <td><%= link_to 'Show', spare, class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs" %></td>
      <% end %>

      <!-- authorization check -->
      <% if can? :edit, Spare %>
       <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_spare_path(spare), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %> </td>
      <% end %>

      <!-- authorization check -->
      <% if can? :destroy, Spare %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', spare, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the #{spare.name}?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs",remote: true %></td>
      <% end %>
      </tr>  
    <% end %>
```

spares_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @spare.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to spares_url, notice: 'Spare was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#li_<%= @spare.id %>").remove()
```

Make sure you have `set_spare` before filter in your controller, before destroy action.
Like this.

```
def set_spare
  @spare = Spare.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: hi, the change is only in the destroy.js.erb file right? . I made those changes , still getting the same error

Comment: Are you closing the tgas properly, like tr and td, the snippet you pasted above is not closing the html tags properly, I build the app from scretch and it worked for me, I will share the whole app code if you say.

Comment: That would of great help if u could share it :)

Comment: Clone this git repo and run https://github.com/subhashsaran/ajax-debugg, and let me know